# Incomprehensible syntax in c/c++!! why can we malloc a buffer like this?

Tags: c, syntax, malloc, sizeof

Today,I noticed a bunch of code that Instantiate a struct like below while  ServiceMsg is a struct.

```
ServiceMsg *msg = (ServiceMsg *)malloc(sizeof * msg);
```

I have never seen malloc can be used like this. Can anyone explain this to me???
size of buffer is often assigned like this    malloc(sizeof(int) * n) as is known to me..

Comment: That's `sizeof(*msg)`, not a multiplication. (And `new msg` would be a million times better (And a smart pointer another million times better again (And there's no language called `C/C++`)))

Comment: @john Why is that?

Comment: @KenY-N You know I think I would have spotted that had it not been for the space between the `*` and `msg`.

Comment: To make it clear to the OP. Parens are only required in `sizeof(X)` if `X` is a type. If `X` is an expression (as above) they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few details that might make it confusing:

- The `sizeof` operator can be used in two ways: either with parenthesis `sizeof(type)`, but then the argument must be a type like `int`. Or without parenthesis `sizeof expr`, then the argument can be an expression. But of course an expression can contain a parenthesis in itself...
- In your case `sizeof *msg` takes the size of the expression `*msg`, which means de-reference the pointer `msg` (it's not the multiplication operator!) so we end up with a "lvalue" temporary variable of type `ServiceMsg`. Which has the size of a `ServiceMsg`.
- Normally, de-referencing a pointer variable at the same line it is declared would be a big no-no, it is not initialized and is not yet pointing at any sensible location. The catch is that the `sizeof` operator does not actually evaluate (execute) its operand, so the expression `*msg` is never executed and de-referencing never happens.

This is why the code works. This style is often even recommended, since you don't have to worry about what type the pointer is pointing at - it's always `type* ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);` regardless of what you are allocating.

The cast to `(ServiceMsg*)` in your code is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!! but what does this mean:  type ptr* = malloc(sizeof *ptr) ?? I change type to int and tried it in my machine,It blocks on compiling.

Comment: @CaiyiZhou It was a typo, fixed. But besides that I meant that instead of `type` you can write any valid type there and it works the same.

Answer (score 3):

In the snippet,

```
  ServiceMsg *msg = (ServiceMsg *)malloc(sizeof * msg);
```

is the same as

```
 ServiceMsg *msg = (ServiceMsg *)malloc( 1* sizeof(*msg));
```

which is better written as

```
 ServiceMsg *msg = malloc(sizeof(*msg));
```

To elaborate, `malloc()` expects a size as the argument, and in this call, the size we are passing is `sizeof(*msg)`, i.e., `sizeof (ServiceMsg )`.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: ... or `ServiceMsg* msg = new ServiceMsg;` or even `auto msg = std::make_unique<ServiceMsg>();`

Comment: @TedLyngmo only if it's CPP, and I won;t use `malloc` in CPP.

Comment: Sigh, I didn't see the double tagging of the question...

Answer (score 0):

It would be more clear if to rewrite this call where the expression looks like a multiplication expression

```
malloc(sizeof * msg);
```

like

```
malloc(sizeof *msg);
```

The `sizeof` operator is defined the following way

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

The expression `*msg` that is dereferencing the pointer `msg` is an unary expression. The type of the expression is determined (in this case it is `ServiceMsg`) and the size of an object of this type is calculated. The expression itself is not evaluated. The compiler only determines its type.

You could this unary expression enclose in parentheses getting a primary expression like

```
malloc(sizeof ( *msg ) );
```

In this this record looks similarly like this record

```
malloc(sizeof ( ServiceMsg ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning that up a little bit, we get

```
ServiceMsg *msg = malloc(sizeof *msg);
```

which is exactly the same as

```
ServiceMsg *msg = malloc(N * sizeof *msg);
```

where `N == 1`.  This is a fairly common idiom in C for dynamically allocating memory:

```
T *p = malloc( N * sizeof *p ); // for any non-function type T
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );
```

or

```
T *p = calloc( N, sizeof *p );
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = calloc( N, sizeof *p );
```

It has the advantage of not repeating type information, so maintenance is easier.

The cast is unnecessary<sup>1</sup>, and since the *type* of the expression `*msg` is `ServiceMessage`, `sizeof *msg == sizeof( ServiceMessage )`.

Remember that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function - parentheses are only required if the operand is a type name like `ServiceMessage` or `int` or `char`, or if it's an arithmetic expression like `1 + 2`.  Since `sizeof` is a unary operator it has higher precedence than an arithmetic operator, so `sizeof 1 + 2` is parsed as `(sizeof 1) + 2`, which probably isn't what you want.

---

1. Unless you're compiling this code as C++ or using an *ancient* K&R implementation.  Prior to C89, the `*alloc` functions returned `char *` instead of `void *`, so a cast was necessary if the target wasn't a `char *`.  C++ does not allow implicit conversion from `void *` to other pointer types, so it requires a cast as well, but if you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using C-style memory management anyway.